# Условие на подсчет limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется столбец  вида

```
1
11
12
2
21
211
3
31
```

Нужно сделать sql-запрос, который бы выводил бы этот столбец полностью, но учитывал в limit только однозначные цифры.
Например, если сделать запрос к этому столбцу

```
*запрос* limit 2
```

то вывелось бы

```
    1
    11
    12
    2
    21
    211
```

Столбец типа varchar, база данных mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можешь сравнить написав в where column < 10

```
select * from table
where column < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Limit ограничивает число строк по количеству, а не по качеству. Возможно, так:

```
select * from table
where column < '3'
order by column
```